# Can't resolve rxjs/*** on angular 5 project

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-ec2, rxjs, angular-cli

I can't run my angular app on amazon ec2. When I execute `ng serve` or `ng serve -c stage` with environment.stage.ts configuration, i'm getting errors as shown on the  screenshot below. The error does not appear when run locally on my pc and project is compiled without errors.

The version of rxjs is 5.5.5.

Angular, angular-cli and node version also below.

[image]

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@angular/router/esm5'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-api-wrapper.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/data-layer-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/marker-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/info-window-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/polyline-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/circle-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/kml-layer-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers/polygon-manager.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/managers'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/http/esm5/http.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/home/ubuntu/b2s_dev/b2s_v2_web/node_modules/@angular/http/esm5'
>   ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

BR,

Comment: Please post your **text** errors as **text**. Corporate proxies make it impossible for some people to see your errors.

Comment: can you share how you write your rxjs imports?

Comment: are you sure you ran "npm install" on the ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes I'm running npm install and here is how I'm import rxjs:

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

Comment: Can you add your package.json to the question please?

Answer (score 0):

try to import rxjs only without observables

Comment: I can't I'm using the observable for generic error function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start-stage": "ng serve --env=stage",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:universal:prod": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false && cpy ./server.js ./dist",
    "serve:universal:prod": "npm run build:universal:prod && cd dist && node server",
    "compile_@agm_core": "babel node_modules/@agm/core -d node_modules/@agm/core --presets es2015",
    "postinstall": "npm run compile_@agm_core"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ngx-disqus": "^2.3.7",
    "nouislider": "^10.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install rxjs compact that will install the latest version of rxjs that is compatible with the Angular version that you are using.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```